# Openshift PostgreSQL connection from Java program

Tags: java, postgresql, openshift

I cannot seem to connect to my PostgreSQL database from my Java program -

My Java code:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
```

Where USERNAME and PASSWORD are correct for the database cartridge on Openshift.

My Java application is in the same cartridge as my database server.

When attempting to access the database, I get a standard Null Pointer exception, and when looking through the logs, I have:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I assume that Openshift isn't allowing programs to connect to internal databases, but I'm not sure how to get around it. Any ideas?

I've tried changing the IP from the environment variables to the Openshift postgres external IP, but I get the same error from that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading the environment variables. $OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST and $OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT are environment variables. If you ssh to the instance and run "env" you will see all environment variables including those. But in your

```
DriverManager.getConnection("...{connection string}...")
```

those variables are not substituted.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29) and [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) on how to read from environment variables.